# Find contacts from a large database via keyword

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good morning all,

Looking for some support with a challenge that is outside my formula-based knowledge (I don't have any VBA knowledge!)

I have a large contacts database downloaded from the internet (paid lead gen website) which contains up to 50 contacts per company. I've been asked to filter out so that I only have the following: Company (left-most column), and the first name, surname, job title and email address of anyone whose job title contains the word "Innovation". I've tried a couple different ways around it (FILTER, XLOOKUP and LEFT/RIGHT formulae) but not figured anything out yet.

I've attached a link so you can see what I mean. Apparently I can't include images or attachments yet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YrLC.png)

Any ideas I'd be extremely grateful!

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a certain pattern in the data, so try:

[image]

Formula in `A6`:

```
=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B1:M3,3),4),FILTER(x,ISERR(FIND("Innovation",INDEX(x,,3)))-1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that in the full set, and it does pull down some of the answers, but not all - any ideas why? (I've done conditional formatting for the word Innovation so I can see that there should be many more answers). I don't know if this would impact it, but the full database goes from A1:GZ247; there are up to 50 contacts per company, including some where multiple contacts might fit our parameters.

Comment: I suppose you need to change the range reference in the formula to `B2:GW247` @Rob?

Comment: Hi, did that so I now have 

=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B1:GZ247,3),4),FILTER(x,ISERR(FIND("Innovation",INDEX(x,,3)))-1))

Seems to have picked up answers quite at random

Comment: @Rob, the answer is based on the pattern of 4 columns per contact. So you just have to use a multiple of 4 columns as per my answer. If that is not working, then somewhere down the line your data does not follow that pattern. Nothing I can help with since you have provided what you have provided.

Comment: no worries and thanks very much for your help. The real dataset is not fully complete, a lot of email addresses are missing, so that's probably throwing it out.

Comment: @rob, than remove the 2nd parameter of the tocol function. This prevents removing empty cells.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, this fixed one of the issues and the other fix was that I needed to amend for a hidden column I hadn't spotted. The other issue I have now is using the output list and finding the Company column (now Column A) by searching the entire database for the string in my contacts list. In your screengrab, this formula would be trying to find A1 in E6, and A3 in E7. I've tried using HLOOKUP but I assume it's going to be the FIND formula you suggested again, which I'm not familiar with...